# visual basic looping issue

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am a new programmer learning Visual Basic. Right now, I'm working on a project about a softball scoreboard. I have been working on this project for a bit, and I am confused on 1 thing.

The thing I am confused on is the proper place to place my loop. I am trying to do a while loop, but when I try it allows me to enter the 7 innings, but once I do it is an infinate loop with the message only seven innings are allowed and it does not display the lblTotal. It works without the loop, but it just doesnt allow me to enter all of the innings back to back. I would really appreciate if you could help me. I feel like I placed the loop in the wrong place.

```
Public Class frmSoftballScoreboard
    Const VALID_MESSAGE As String = "Enter valid runs value"
    Const ONLY_MESSAGE As String = "Only seven innings are allowed"
    'Declaring array
    Dim scores(6) As Double
    'declaring variables
    Dim runs As String
    Dim runningScore As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim out As Double

    'page load event
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstScores.Items.Add("Runs : Running Score")
    End Sub
    'Enter score button
    Private Sub btnScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScore.Click
        Do While runs <= 7
            If i < scores.Length Then
                'display inputbox to the user
                runs = InputBox("Enter score for " & (i + 1) & " innings", "Score")
                'if runs is entered
                If runs < 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf runs <> "" Then
                    'parse the value of runs
                    If (Double.TryParse(runs, out)) Then
                        'parse the runs and add it to the array scores()
                        scores(i) = Double.Parse(runs)
                        runningScore += scores(i)
                        'add the rainfall value to the listbox along with month name
                        lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)
                        'increment the value of i
                        i = i + 1
                    Else
                        'display error message
                        MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
                        lblTotal.Text = ""
                    End If
                Else
                    'if runs is empty then display error message
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter runs for " & i & "innings")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(ONLY_MESSAGE)
            End If
            If runs < 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
            End If
        Loop
        'calculate total runs And display on the lable
        If scores(6) = 7 Then
            lblTotal.Text = String.Format("final score is {0}", scores.Sum())
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub mnuClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuClear.Click
        lstScores.Items.Clear()
        lblTotal.Text = ""
        'reset i to 0
        i = 0
    End Sub
    'Exit Menu click
    Private Sub mnuExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
        'close application
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should do for this project what you should do for all: pick up a pen and paper and write down the steps your code will need to perform.  You need to break things down into the smallest possible steps and formalise each one and then, when you've written them all out, you will have an algorithm. There's no programming up to there so no programming experience necessary. You then write code to implement that algorithm. There cam then be no confusion about where to put the loop because the algorithm will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While runs <= 7
```

'runs' variable should be updated (adding +1) within the 'Do While' loop in order to be able to satisfy the condition and break out.

```
   (...)
   runs += 1
Loop
```